# Execute a function inside array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Is it possible to execute an anonymous function (also, defined inside the array) from inside the of the array ?

```
return [
    //execute?
    function() {
        //logic
    }
];
```

Or should I define it outside and only then call it?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can enclose the function in parentheses and invoke it like this:

```
return [
    (function() { return 42; })()
];
```

which is the same as

```
return [
    42
];
```

However, why would you want to do this? It will only serve to make the code less readable. It would be much better to simply have a separate variable that holds the closure and invoke that as required instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this using `call_user_func` function:

```
function test(){
    return [
        call_user_func(function(){
            return "I was executed inside array! wow!";
          })  
    ];
}

print_r(test());

// the output:
Array
(
    [0] => I was executed inside array! wow!
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return [
    call_user_func(function(){
        // logic executed
    })
];
```