# Populating Nested Array Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8.x and php 7.4. I am trying to return data for a javascript quiz app called 'slickQuiz' and it must be formed like this:

```
{ 
            "q": "What number is the letter A in the English alphabet?",
            "a": [
                {"option": "8",      "correct": false},
                {"option": "14",     "correct": false},
                {"option": "1",      "correct": true},
                {"option": "23",     "correct": false} // no comma here
            ],
            "correct": "<p><span>That's right!</span> The letter A is the first letter in the alphabet!</p>",
            "incorrect": "<p><span>Uhh no.</span> It's the first letter of the alphabet. Did you actually <em>go</em> to kindergarden?</p>" // no comma here
   },
```

I am trying to loop through my data in my controller like this:

```
foreach ($questions as $q) {
            $jsondata[] = [
            "q" => $q->content,
            "a" => [
            foreach ($q->answers as $a) {
                        "option" => $a->content,
                        "correct" => $a->correct,
            }
         ]
        ]
        }
```

I get this error:

```
ParseError
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to prepare the content for "a" first outside of the jsondata append. Then use the prepared "a" within the append on $jsondata

Comment: prepare inside of foreach ($questions as $q) {

Comment: I tried and can't get it

Comment: Git it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I eneded up doing this from user1915746 comment:

```
foreach ($questions as $q) {
            foreach ($q->answers as $a) {
                $adata[] = [
                    "option" => $a->content,
                    "correct" => $a->correct,
                ];
            }
            $jsondata[] = [
                "q" => $q->content,
                "a" => $adata,

            ];
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Another approach is the solution described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195486/execute-a-function-inside-array
But in my opinion it is much less readable than your solution.